# How to properly install gulp v4.0.0-alpha.3 using npm?

Tags: git, npm, gulp, gulp-4

I tried to install gulp version 4 alpha 3 by using:

**sudo npm install gulpjs/gulp#v4.0.0-alpha.3 -g**

And got the following errors:

**npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 4.0 git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git /Users/admin/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4a9cf932
npm ERR! /Users/admin/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4a9cf932/.git: Permission denied**

I've cleaned npm cache several times and it still didn't work.

When I tried 
sudo npm install gulp@next -g or npm install -g , the respective versions can be installed properly.

Is there any difference for installation prerequisites among gulp3.9, gulp4.0 and gulp4.0 alpha ?

Comment: Why would you want an alpha if the stable release is out?

Comment: Coz it's required by the project for some reasons and I have no right to change the configuration file. And other developers in the project could install it properly.

Comment: Did you manage to install this version?